# How to filter distinct regex matches with SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I am querying a (kind of) bibliographic database and would like to find all the distinct matches of a certain regex (matching the signature of typescripts (TS) and manuscripts (MS)); i.e. I would like to return all documents that are currently in the database.

I came up with

```
SELECT ?document
WHERE
{
  {
    ?documentURI a witt:MS;
         rdfs:label ?document.
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?documentURI a witt:TS;
         rdfs:label ?document.
  }
  FILTER (regex(?document, "(Ms|Ts)\\-((1|2|3)\\d{2}\\w?\\d?)"))
}
```

([endpoint](https://sparql.ub.uib.no/dataset.html?tab=query&ds=/wab#query=PREFIX%20witt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fwittgensteinsource%2Font%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fdocument%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3FdocumentURI%20a%20witt%3AMS%3B%0A%09%09%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fdocument.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3FdocumentURI%20a%20witt%3ATS%3B%0A%09%09%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fdocument.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20FILTER%20(regex(%3Fdocument%2C%20%22(Ms%7CTs)%5C%5C-((1%7C2%7C3)%5C%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C%5Cw%3F%5C%5Cd%3F)%22))%0A%7D%0A%0A)); this returns all the signatures but I would like to filter the result for the *distinct* regex matches, i.e. the distinct signatures up to and excluding the comma.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution with strbefore:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?document
WHERE
{
  {
    ?documentURI a witt:MS;
         rdfs:label ?documentFull.
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?documentURI a witt:TS;
         rdfs:label ?documentFull.
  }
  BIND (strbefore(?documentFull, ",") AS ?document)
}
```

[Try it](https://sparql.ub.uib.no/dataset.html?tab=query&ds=/wab#query=PREFIX%20witt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fwittgensteinsource%2Font%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fdocument%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3FdocumentURI%20a%20witt%3AMS%3B%0A%09%09%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FdocumentFull.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3FdocumentURI%20a%20witt%3ATS%3B%0A%09%09%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FdocumentFull.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20BIND%20(strbefore(%3FdocumentFull%2C%20%22%2C%22)%20AS%20%3Fdocument)%0A%7D%0A%0A).

Would appreciate opinions on the query though, is this effective/good style?

Comment: makes sense to use this simple function as long as the data doesn't contain corner-cases. And in general it's more efficient to evaluate compared to expensive regex

Comment: for compactness, you could avoid repeating particular patterns: `SELECT ?document
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?type {witt:MS witt:TS}
  ?documentURI a ?type ;
   rdfs:label ?documentFull.
 
  BIND(strbefore(?documentFull, ",") AS ?document)
}`

Comment: or `PREFIX witt: <http://purl.org/wittgensteinsource/ont/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?document
WHERE
{
  {
    ?documentURI a witt:MS
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?documentURI a witt:TS
  }
  ?documentURI rdfs:label ?documentFull.
  BIND (strbefore(?documentFull, ",") AS ?document)
}`